# Differentiating between "Mr" and the Mr in "Mrs" using R

Tags: r, gsub

I'm using grep to replace "Mr" and "Mrs" with "Mr." and "Mrs.", but whenever I enter

> gsub("Mr", "Mr.", data$Title)

it also causes all of the "Mrs" to turn into "Mr.s", which is not exactly what I'm looking for :P

> gsub("Mr\s", "Mr." data$Title)

doesn't work either, as R (I think) doesn't recognize that space after the Mr.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In R you need to escape things twice, once for R and once for the regular expression.  `gsub('Mr\\s', 'Mr. ', data$Title)` or `gsub('Mr ', 'Mr. ', data$Title)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
gsub("(Mrs?)", "\\1.", c("Mr Smith", "Mrs Smith"))
#[1] "Mr. Smith"  "Mrs. Smith"
```

Comment: Great solution, and works for when there's no space after the title (like OP wanted).

Answer (score 3):

```
> gsub("Mr([^s])", "Mr.\\1", c("Mr fdfvgg", "Mrs FLkm"))
[1] "Mr. fdfvgg" "Mrs FLkm"
```

Comment: It does work, but the issue with that is my "Mr" doesn't have a space after it. It's more like Mrfdfvgg and MrsFLkm.

Comment: `[^s]` means match any character which is not an s. It doesnt mean a space. @eddi answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think eddi's answer is better, but here is an alternate way to get "Mr" without getting "Mrs":

```
gsub("Mr\\b", "Mr.", c("Mr", "Mrs"))

[1] "Mr." "Mrs"
```

The `\\b` indicates a word boundary.

Answer (score -2):

**You can simply run a loop on R directly
by checking the length of data$Title

---

if the length==2 => data$Title[i]<-"Mr."
else data$Title[i]<-"Mrs."**

Comment: -1 Not formatted, no explanation of what you're looping over, and I'm pretty sure you mean `nchar` not `length`.